# setting innodb_strict_mode = 0 how will affect database?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

Currently I am working on project which has requirement to set 300 columns in MySql database so after setting it I was getting `Row size too large error` which I have solved by setting `innodb_strict_mode = 0` in mysql config file.

If after creating table If I will remove this setting `innodb_strict_mode = 0` , does it will affect for already created table or table related query.

Is it recommended solution or should I prefer another solution?

Comment: Read [it with care and attention](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_strict_mode)

Comment: You've solved getting the error, not that row size is too large. I would carefully reconsider the table design.

Comment: Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there are probably things that we can suggest to shrink it.